# Create Nuget package for Xamarin.Forms custom control

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, nuget

I currently have a Xamarin.Forms app, and I want to extract a control as a Nuget package but I'm not sure what approach is better.
Let's say my control is a custom Button, with custom renderers, colors and styles from App.xaml, custom fonts and images(placed in the .iOS and .Android projects), etc.
My dll should not only contain the .xaml and .xaml.cs files of the custom control, but also those resources that I mentioned above, right?
The current approach that I'm using is to create another .NET Standard class library(let's name it Core project) which will contain shared resources from my app and the custom control project, and then create the .NET Standard project for the custom control. This last project will be published as a NuGet package.
I'm currently facing the following issues:

1. The Core project will reference other projects from the solution as well as other Nuget packages. If I use 
   `NuGet Pack -IncludeReferencedProjects`
   then the projects from my solution are added, but the referenced Nuget packages are not, so when I try to build a test app that references my custom control Nuget package, it says that I have to install a bunch of Nuget packages, and I don't want this. So if my custom control references MvvM.Cross, then every app who install my project can't build until it also installs Mvvm.Cross. Can I do this automatically?
2. I have to share the ResourceDictionary from the Core project to the custom control project. I used this but when I run the test app it says that resources are missing:

```
<ContentView.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <myCoreNamespace:myCoreThemeFile/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
</ContentView.Resources>
```

3. How do I include the assets that are placed in the .Android and .iOS projects(fonts, images, custom renderers)?

Comment: I have the exact same question. Were you able to find any solution?

Comment: anyone find any solution ?

Comment: Did you find the answer?